# Identify Null values, and missed parameters during DeSerialization and assigning Null values to Default Values

Tags: asp.net, json, c#-4.0, json.net

Here is My question How to Identify Null values, and missed parameters during 
DeSerialization and assigning Null values to Default Values.

The sample code I tried Like this for assigning null values

```
public class RoomImage
{
     private string useurl = "~/no-picture-available.jpg";

     [DefaultValue("~/no-picture-available.jpg")]
     public string url { get { return useurl; } set { useurl = value; } }
}
```

But not working during the DeSerialization process - can you share me any ideas you have  how to achieve this .

Comment: What does the json look like before you deserialize it?  How is it being serialized in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this particular example you've posted, you do not have to handle `null` values during deserialization. You can read the `DefaultValue` attribute on the `url` property of `RoomImage` class. Here is the code:

```
public class RoomImage
{
    private string useurl;

    [DefaultValue("~/no-picture-available.jpg")]
    public string url
    {
        get
        {
            return !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(useurl) 
                       ? useurl
                       : ((DefaultValueAttribute)
                          (TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(this)["url"].Attributes[
                              typeof (DefaultValueAttribute)])).Value.ToString();
        }
        set { useurl = value; }
    }
}
```

Using this code, if a value is assigned to the `url` property, when you try to access it, it will return that particular value. If the `url` property is `null`, `empty` or string that consists of white spaces only, the `DefaultValue` will be returned.